# Select the element with a variable class

Tags: jquery, css

i am not able to select the element with class of a particular value for the below line

My HTML is

```
<ul class=nav>
   <li class="home">
       <a href="">HOME </a>
   </li>
   <li class="bye">
       <a href="">BYE </a>
   </li> 
</ul>

<script>
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
   $('.home').addClass('.newhome').removeClass('.home');
    alert("done");
});
</script>
```

My CSS is

```
li.newhome {
    background: #678fef no-repeat;
     color:#fff;
    }

li.home{ 
 background: #666 no-repeat;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELbCx/14/).

Comment: shouldn't you be using $(this) instead of $this? and what's `[]`?

Comment: ...and use addClass instead.

Comment: That code doesn't really make much sense. What is $this. why are you storing the classes like that in the first place, why are you setting the attribute and not the property (className) with one of the many methods in jQuery etc. Explain as simple as possible what the intended functionality is, and maybe someone will suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: and your `<a>` tags are useless if you don't put anything in. Unless you're going to put an background image as a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lastclickedclass=".home";
var updatedlastclass=".newhome";
```

`$(lastclickedclass)` is equivalent to `$('.home')`

for adding class you can use

```
$('.home').addClass('.newhome');
```

if you want to replace class

```
$('.home').addClass('.newhome').removeClass('.home');
```

if you want to refer in current code use

```
$(this).find('.home').addClass('.newhome');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the cleaned up fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ELbCx/15/.

What you just copy and pasted isn't even how jQuery works. If jQuery can't read it, it can't execute it.

Code is here:

**HTML**

```
<ul class=nav>
    <li class="home">HOME</li>
    <li class="bye">BYE</li> 
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('home bye');
    $(this).addClass("newHome");
});
```

EDIT: Added `removeClass` to remove the existing classes.

Comment: yep i m tried expanding the code further plz see this when i click on bye the home1 class shud be reset to home but it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/genius2k/ELbCx/18/...but it doesn't plz help

Comment: You've already accepted Tushar's answer, now all you need to do is figure it out to put it into code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace the existing class with a class by clicking on 'li' then it could be helpful..

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('class')).addClass("newHome");
 });
```